# Starting a simpy simulation run using a callback

Tags: python, process, callback, simpy

How can I write some simulation code (including waiting for events) from a callback?

Reducing my process to the simplest possible example, I want to start some executable code when an event occurs in my simpy simulation. What I did was set that executable code as a callback for an event. That executable code itself has some simpy event handling in it, specifically a timeout. In my real code, this happens within a process, but this simplified version, where `event` is in main displays the same problem behavior:

```
import simpy
if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = simpy.Environment()

    def simulationRun(event):
        print("Starting a run at time [%i]" % env.now)
        yield env.timeout(5)
        print("Ending a run at time [%i]" % env.now)

    event = env.timeout(5)
    event.callbacks.append(simulationRun)

    print("Starting simulation.")
    env.run(20)
    print("End of simulation.")
```

My expected output is:

```
Starting simulation.
Starting a run at time [5]
Ending a run at time [10]
End of simulation.
```

However, my actual output is:

```
Starting simulation.
End of simulation.
```

When I remove the yield command, I get:

```
Starting simulation.
Starting a run at time [5]
Ending a run at time [5]
End of simulation.
```

Clearly the callback is set correctly but the whole point is to simulate the timeout in `simulationRun`. How can I run some simulation code (including waiting for an event) in code from a callback?

This uses Python 3.4.2 and simpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not work with callbacks directly.  Best practise is to use another
process that starts the `simulation_run()` for you:

```
import simpy


def simulation_run(env):
    print("Starting a run at time [%i]" % env.now)
    yield env.timeout(5)
    print("Ending a run at time [%i]" % env.now)


def starter(env):
    yield env.timeout(5)
    env.process(simulation_run(env))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(starter(env))
    print("Starting simulation.")
    env.run(20)
    print("End of simulation.")
```

Since this is a relatively common pattern, we have a utility function built into 
SimPy which does exactly this:

```
import simpy
import simpy.util


def simulation_run(env):
    print("Starting a run at time [%i]" % env.now)
    yield env.timeout(5)
    print("Ending a run at time [%i]" % env.now)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = simpy.Environment()
    simpy.util.start_delayed(env, simulation_run(env), delay=5)
    print("Starting simulation.")
    env.run(20)
    print("End of simulation.")
```

Note: You should always pass a reference to the Environment into your processes
instead of using the one from the global scope.  It may seem tedious, but you
can run into any kind of problems if you later restructure or refacor your code
and the global env is no longer what you expected or no longer available.

Comment: I note your points that (a) I should pass `env` as a parameter instead of using a global and (b) simpy.util.start_delayed addresses the issue of waiting on a timeout event to start a process and (c) one should not manipulate the callback set directly.  I will say that I am still tempted to manipulate the callback set directly, because in my simulation I am not keying off a timeout event, but an upstream event (actually a "entity has arrived in a queue" event.) For this event, I defined a queue explicitly, so that I could evaluate queue depths and wait times more easily...

Comment: ...Perhaps I will post a separate question comparing the explicit queue that I defined versus the implicit queue of a shared resource.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the callback is not a process, therefore it is not running in the simpy simulation engine in such a way that it can be stopped and restarted by the engine. What you need is a process. You can make your current `simulationRun` a process by starting that code from a separate callback function, as shown below.

```
import simpy  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = simpy.Environment()

    def simulationRun():
        print("Starting a run at time [%i]" % env.now)
        yield env.timeout(5)
        print("Ending a run at time [%i]" % env.now)

    def callback(event):
        s = simulationRun()
        env.process(s)

    event = env.timeout(5)
    event.callbacks.append(callback)

    print("Starting simulation.")
    env.run(20)
    print("End of simulation.")
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying event callbacks usage